# Placing indexes on a MySQL table using JPA/Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, indexing

I would like to set indexes on multiple columns within a single table in MySQL database. After reading this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-indexes), I'm not 100% sure which approach to use.

So my (simplified) table looks like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "loan")
public class Loan {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "loan_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "amount", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private double amount;

    @Column(name = "rate", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private double rate;

    @Column(name = "payments", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private int payments;

    @Column(name = "pmt", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private double pmt;
}
```

I will have a lot of search queries, for instance:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  Loan loan
    WHERE  loan.amount =: amount
      AND  loan.rate =: rate
      AND  loan.payments =: payments
      AND  loan.pmt =: pmt
    LIMIT  1;
```

Now, I would like to index fields in `WHERE` clause. Essentially, I would like to achieve effect of a "composite key" where in table `loan` there are only unique combinations of mentioned fields. So I cannot have two rows all with some values.

Is there such a configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ou can add a UNIQUE constraint, which would be indexed automatocally

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = 
  { 
  @UniqueConstraint(name = "UniqueWhereclause", columnNames = { "amount", "rate","payments","pmt" })})
```

or you can create an index alone

```
@Entity
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "loan", indexes = {
    @Index(columnList = "amount, rate,payments,pmt", name = "name_idx") })
```

Comment: But can't two loans have the same 4 values?

Comment: you said you wanted the 4 columns as unique that is what the first makes, if there are duplicates you need the second. i don't know your code or content so i gave you both solutions

Answer (score 1):

`DOUBLE` is likely to cause trouble for you.  Switch to `DECIMAL` with a suitable number of decimal places -- so that `=` can be tested correctly.

Also, that's a strange combination of 4 things to use in the `WHERE`.  Any 3 of those columns *should* (mathematically) determine the value for the 4th.

Does the table also have the name of the person taking out the loan?  Or is this table a list of possible loans?  As rates change, so you add more rows to the table?  But why have the table if 3 columns can be used to compute the 4th?

Comment: Tnx for DECIMAL/DOUBLE advice. 4th value can be latter difficult to calculate (now is simple) so I decide to store it to the db. This is a table which contains data/rates on loans.

Comment: `rate` might be `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`; shouldn't `pmt` be an exact amount of dollars and cents?  (Or whatever currency.)